# Leveraging the Flask application context in a custom URL converter

Tags: python, flask, neo4j, werkzeug

I'm experiencing a similar problem to [Passing application context to custom converter using the Application Factory pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33856007/passing-application-context-to-custom-converter-using-the-application-factory-pa) where I'm using a custom URL converter for converting a Neo4j graph database ID into a node object, i.e.,

```py
import atexit
from flask import Flask
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase
from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter


class NodeConverter(BaseConverter):
    def to_python(self, value):
        with driver.session() as session:
            cursor = session.run('MATCH (n {id: $id}) RETURN n', id=value)
            return cursor.single().values()[0]


app = Flask(__name__)
app.url_map.converters['node'] = NodeConverter
driver = GraphDatabase.driver('bolt://localhost')
atexit.register(lambda driver=driver: driver.close())


@app.route('/<node:node>')
def test(node):
    print node


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Though this approach leverages a single database connection there are a couple of major drawbacks: i) the database connection cannot be configured via the Flask config, and ii) if the database fails so does the Flask app.

To counter this I created a local extension per http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/extensiondev/, i.e.,

```py
from flask import _app_ctx_stack, Flask
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase
from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter


class MyGraphDatabase(object):
    def __init__(self, app=None):
        self.app = app

        if app is not None:
            self.init_app(app)

    def init_app(self, app):

        @app.teardown_appcontext
        def teardown(exception):
            ctx = _app_ctx_stack.top

            if hasattr(ctx, 'driver'):
                ctx.driver.close()

    @property
    def driver(self):
        ctx = _app_ctx_stack.top

        if ctx is not None and not hasattr(ctx, 'driver'):
            ctx.driver = GraphDatabase.driver(app.config['NEO4J_URI'])

        return ctx.driver


class NodeConverter(BaseConverter):
    def to_python(self, value):
        with app.app_context():
            with db.driver.session() as session:
                cursor = session.run('MATCH (n {id: $id}) RETURN n', id=value)
                return cursor.single().values()[0]


db = MyGraphDatabase()
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('app.cfg')
app.url_map.converters['node'] = NodeConverter
db.init_app(app)


@app.route('/<node:node>')
def test(node):
    print node


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This issue is given that the URL converter is outside of the app context I needed to include the following block,

```py
with app.app_context():
    ...
```

where a temporary app context is created during URL parsing and then discarded immediately which seems suboptimal from a performance perspective. Is this the correct approach for this?

The other problem with this configuration is that one needs to be cognizant  of potential circular references when the converter and application reside in different files since the `NodeConverter` requires the `app` and the `app` registers the `NodeConverter`.

Comment: I was playing around just to find a way of doing this, and I added `app` as a class instance. Then in `create_app()`, assign the variable: `MyCustomConverter.app = app`. Probably not efficient, but at least easier on the eye.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to leverage the Flask application context in a custom URL converter is to use the `current_app` proxy object instead of the `app` instance. This way, you can access the current application context without creating a temporary one. For example, you can modify your `NodeConverter` class as follows:

```
from flask import current_app

class NodeConverter(BaseConverter):
    def to_python(self, value):
        with current_app.db.driver.session() as session:
            cursor = session.run('MATCH (n {id: $id}) RETURN n', id=value)
            return cursor.single().values()[0]
```

Note that I also changed the `db` attribute to be a property of the current application, instead of a global variable. This is a good practice to avoid circular imports and namespace conflicts. You can do this by setting the `db` attribute in your `init_app` method of your `MyGraphDatabase` class:

```
def init_app(self, app):
    app.db = self
    ...
```

This way, you can access the database driver from the current application context, without importing the `db` object from another module.

Another possible way to leverage the Flask application context in a custom URL converter is to use the `g` object, which is a global namespace for storing data during a single request context. You can store the database driver in the `g` object in a `before_request` handler, and then access it from your `NodeConverter` class. For example, you can do something like this:

```
from flask import g

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.driver = db.driver

class NodeConverter(BaseConverter):
    def to_python(self, value):
        with g.driver.session() as session:
            cursor = session.run('MATCH (n {id: $id}) RETURN n', id=value)
            return cursor.single().values()[0]
```

This way, you can avoid creating a temporary application context for each URL conversion, and reuse the same database driver for the whole request. However, you should be careful not to modify the `g` object in other places, as it might affect the behavior of your converter.